# Why it will still appear "Incorrect account or password or user type" after I login successful？

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've tried but just can't figure out why, thanks for helping if there is any solution for this `JFrame`.

```
if (userInfo != null ) {    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LoginSuccessful");
    dispose();                  
    new ChooseRoomFrame(userInfo,UserRoomDetails,UserDao).setVisible(true);
}                   
if(Staff != null & rdbtnStaff.isSelected()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful");
    dispose();
    new StaffFrame(userInfo, UserRoomDetails,UserDao).setVisible(true);                 
}       
if(user.isEmpty() & pwd.isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please insert Username and Password");
}               
else if(user.isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please insert Username");
}
else if (pwd.isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please insert Password");
}   
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect account or password or user type");
}
```

Comment: Edit your code. Don't post an update in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems an incorrect logic. try return in every situation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking if the password or username are empty, the final else statement will execute when the user and password are **not empty**.

```
else {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect account or password or user type");
}
```

Remove this else statement and your code will work as expected.

This is because you already covered the situations where one or both of the fields are empty. That means the final else lacking an if will execute when they aren't empty.